# Getting a user ID from a mention

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to get a Users ID from a mention. I am making a user info command so the author of the message will not always be them so I cannot do `message.author.id`. I have used substrings to split the command into the command itself and the mention but I cannot turn the mention into an ID.

I am aware that discords mentions are actually `<@USERID>`, which is another way I could get the ID. Please tell me if I am able to get rid of the `<@>` so I am left with the ID, or turn the mention itself into an one using another method. I have looked through the docs and I am not aware of anything that could help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that in two ways: if you want to use the mention as an argument, you can remove the mention characters with regex, like this: `yourstring.replace(/[\\<>@#&!]/g, "");`.
The other way to do that is to get the first mention in the message and then the user's id: `message.mentions.users.first().id`.

Comment: Thanks! I have used the bottom solution and it worked perfectly! I am quite new to JS so regex confuses me.

Comment: Regex confuses everyone XD

Answer (score 1):

I know the poster already got their answer, but those looking to get all of the ids, there is a different approach:

```
// Listen for messages
client.on( Events.MessageCreate, async ( message ) => {

    // Get any mentions
    const mentions = message.mentions;
    if ( !mentions ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the mentioned users
    const usersList = Array.from( mentions.users );

    // Iter the users
    usersList.forEach( function ( user ) {

        // Check if they mentioned the bot
        const userID = user[0];

        // ... Do what you want with each id
        
    } );
    return;
});
```